# pveam shows packages for wrong architecture

Tags: proxmox

I am currently setting up proxmox on raspberry pi, which in itself works fine. However pveeam shows only amd64 images when running `pveam update`/`pveam available` (which don't work for obvious reasons). Based on the listings shown on linuxcontainers.org there are plenty of arm64/aarch64 packages out there though, so to me this seems like pveam is filtering based on (wrong) architecture somewhere.

I *assume* there is some configuration to force pveam to use the correct architecture, but it seems to be an extraordinarily badly documented piece of code.

If anyone has some insights or can tell me how else to get the appropriate packages into proxmox I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: if I read correctly, then I assume that you don't checked the source.list.d because it is known that proxmox forces amd64 architecture

Comment: @djdomi care to be a little less cryptic?

Comment: truly,  I was in the situation that I wanted to use my mobile workstation. Do I want to use Linux Gaming and had Proxmox installed, due to the fact I tried and failed also with the drivers, I ran out of time to follow-up why these drivers which I think I also needed are blacklisted by default on proxmox  - i assume that this question might be better solved on the proxmox forum IMHO